# how to only show number with truncate or css

Tags: css, django, jinja2

I want to display `S1` only instead of `season 1`. Thus I need to truncate `season` and put only `1` and add `"S"` at the front.

```
<a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">
    {{ all_episode.season}}
</a>
```

How do I truncate the word `"season"`?

Edit: 
Here's what I did again

I created templatetag folder inside my app 
then added **init**.py and seasonify.py
and inside seasonify.py I added

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def seasonify(value):
    return value.replace('season', 'S')
```

then inside my template 
I added

```
{% load seasonify %}
and {% episode.season|seasonify %}
```

Comment: Is the value of `all_episode.season` "season 1"?

Comment: @sean yes. I'm using for loop of all_episode. so season1,2,3,...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). The logic is simple:

```
@register.filter
def seasonify(value):
    return value.replace('season', 'S')
```

then simply use it in your templates:

```
{{ all_episode.season | seasonify }}
```

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) for details on where to put this code.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer. I've never used a template filter before. do I just add that in my views.py?

Comment: No, you should create a separate file in the `templatetags` directory. Please see the link at the end of my answer for details. It is not complicated.

Comment: I did it like the document says but I get TemplateSyntaxError at /
'seasonify' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Comment: @rosababy The name of the directory should be `templatetags`, not `templatetag`. Is that a typo?

Comment: unfortunately I put templatetags on my side

Comment: Did you restart the development server?

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9157 this is what im trying to achieve but so hard

Comment: Now we are jumping from topic to topic. Have you resolved your original issue? Does the custom filter work now?

Comment: it's okay I solved it by using cut multiple times. not the best way but it works